# Unable to delete files in Centos 6.10

Tags: linux, centos

Below is my file permission

```
$ ll
ls: cannot access asclient.config: Input/output error
total 0
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? asclient.config
```

I am trying to delete the files 'asclient.config' but getting error.

$ rm -rf asclient.config

rm: cannot remove `asclient.config': Input/output error

Please help to fix this issue

Comment: Check `dmesg` for problems.

Comment: **dmesg outptut**

1._EXT4-fs error (device xvdc): mb_free_blocks: double-free of inode 229424's block 944327(bit 26823 in group 28)
EXT4-fs error (device xvdc): mb_free_blocks: double-free of inode 229433's block 944333(bit 26829 in group 28)_

2._EXT4-fs error (device xvdc): ext4_lookup: deleted inode referenced: 231260
EXT4-fs error (device xvdc): ext4_lookup: deleted inode referenced: 231260
EXT4-fs error (device xvdc): ext4_lookup: deleted inode referenced: 231260_

Comment: You have some form of filesystem corruption. Make sure you have a backup of any vital data before doing anything else. If you have vital data that you have not backed up or can not back up, take the drive or image to a data recovery company. Attempting to use advice from the Internet to fix your issues can result in additional permanent data loss.

Answer (score 2):

The filesystem, or underlying disk, is damaged in some way.  You can attempt to repair the filesystem with fsck.  See: "man fsck" for more information.